# @Value annotation in java interfaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, annotations

I have an interface parent class lets call it `IParent` here. There are two child classes that implements this interface `ChildA` and `ChildB`. `ChildA` also extends another class `OtherClass`.

```
public interface IParent{

    @Value("${car.color:blue}")
    public final String color = "blue";

    public int doSomething();
}


public class ChildA extends OtherClass implements IParent{
    public int doSomething();

}


public class ChildB implements IParent{
    public int doSomething();
}
```

I want to use `iParent.color` in my application but I want `color` to be read from a settings file, since the variable is final in an interface it does not work. The reason I cannot move this to the derived classes because I don't want a type conversion where ever I use the derived classes. Any idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: You can't. That's literally impossible due to the constraints of the java programming language.

Comment: Is it possible to move the variable to another class but still have the object in the interface?

Comment: Note that `color` is actually `public static final` i.e. a constant. All variables inside interfaces are `static`. Interfaces shouldn't (and can't) have any state.